# Pods are not rescheduling to failure node ,when node come alive

Tags: kubernetes

My situation is ,I have 5 nodes having K8 cluster .Initially pods are distributed across the 5 node. Sometime we need to restart particular node server. Then that node goes down and and pod will created on another node. But once failed/down node comes up ,no pods are creating in it automatically, as replica number already reached .We need all node have minimum 1 pods to run .Could please help on this

Comment: Try using node affinity/anti-affinity

Answer (score 0):

> We need all node have minimum 1 pods to run

Instead of running the **Deployment**, you can run the **Daemon** **set** if you want to run a minimum of one **1 pod** to run on the node.

So if anytime new comes to the cluster it will have one replica running of your **POD**.

Read more daemon set : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

You can spread also replicas if running as deployment however it would be tricky to manage with [Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/), [POD topology spread](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/)

Comment: But Daemon set  only allow one pod per node ? if i need to increase replica whether it works?

Comment: in that case you can create multiple deamon set with a different name, otherwise you have to go with affinity and topology approach.